# Can't login to mysql after installation on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 19.10 I installed mysql with `sudo apt install mysql-server`.  I ran `sudo mysql_secure_installation utility` and set the root password.  Then when I try to login with `mysql -u root -p` I get `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

Seriously?  A database I can't login to.  What do I have to do to login to a new installation of mysql?

Thanks.

Comment: try this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: you can try resetting root password

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and tried many things, and what worked for me is using sudo before trying to log in:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Then when logged in, I used:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Hope it helps!